# HPPC DoubleOpenHashSet Clear() Method

Tags: java, hashset

I'm using the HPPC package and I had a question.  In the [API](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/download/hppc/0.5.4/api/) it says the following for the DoubleOpenHashSet.clear() method:

```
Removes all elements from this collection.
Does not release internal buffers.
```

What exactly does the second line imply?  Does that mean that the cleared elements won't be garbage collected?  (I need them to be garbage collected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code you'll see that this method:

https://github.com/carrotsearch/hppc/blob/master/hppc-core/src/main/templates/com/carrotsearch/hppc/KTypeOpenHashSet.java#L486

- clears the buffer arrays for primitive types (to the default value)
- clears object buffers to null (so that objects can be garbage collected)
- does not release or shrink the buffers themselves (so that arrays are still kept and referenced).

So "Does not release internal buffers." talks about the last bullet (if you have a large collection then it won't release the buffer arrays; may be worth to discard the entire object instead of clearing it).